# PayPal for Indian Rupees (INR) any solution

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am developing online shopping website, In shopping website all product priced are in Indian Rupees (INR). I am going to integrate My shopping cart to PayPal payment gateway.
I knew that PayPal does not support INR. So I have to convert INR to USD.
Is there any API service to convert INR to USD as automatically?,
If yes, Please give the details about that...

Answer (score 8):

You can use the Google calculator API.

Here is a PHP example:

```
function currency_converter($from_Currency,$to_Currency,$amount) {
  $url = "http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=$amount$from_Currency=?$to_Currency";      

  $amount = urlencode($amount);
  $from_Currency = urlencode($from_Currency);
  $to_Currency = urlencode($to_Currency);

  $ch = curl_init();
  $timeout = 0;
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
  curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_USERAGENT , "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1)");    
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
  $rawdata = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  $data = explode('"', $rawdata);
  $data = explode(' ', $data['3']);
  $var = $data['0'];

  return round($var,2);
}
```

Comment: Thank'ssssss a lot man it solved my problem, it is such a simple solution

Comment: this is not the exact solution.

Answer (score 5):

You can take a look at: http://www.programmableweb.com/api/currency-rates

Answer (score 1):

I think you didn't need to convert INR to USD for Paypal:(If you are using woocommerce)

Write a simple code in function.php file

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_paypal_supported_currencies', 'add_paypal_valid_currency' ); 

function add_paypal_valid_currency( $currencies ) { 
     array_push ( $currencies , 'INR' ); // ADD YOUR DESIRE CURRENCY
     return $currencies; 
}
```